# Imgproc.undistort() seems missing in OpenCV4

Tags: java, opencv

Java video app uses

```
Imgproc.undistort(frameIn,frameout_undist,cameraMatrix,distCoeffs,camUndistortMatrix);
```

to flatten a radially distorted image with versions up to `OpenCV 3.4.3`. My upgrade to `OpenCV 4.1.1` just broke this call and I cannot find the equivalent function in the new API. I provide the distorted image `frameIn`, a buffer for the undistorted image `frameout_undist`, the camera and distance coefficients `cameraMatrix` and `distCoeffs`, and the optimal undistortion matrix derived from `Calib3d.getOptimalNewCameraMatrix()`. I was hoping someone would point me to the approve way to undistort images in Opencv 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function has moved to the Calib3d module

```
Calib3d.undistort(frameIn,frameout_undist,cameraMatrix,distCoeffs);
```

Also you can search the answer for this and similar issues in the [API for OpenCV modules](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/)